# (HTML CSS) trying to make certain div responsive

Tags: html, css

I made 2 divs inside container div, and I gave them the element inline block, I wanted them to be side by side. like 1 > 2, not on top of each other.
they look great in my screen size (24inch)
but once the screen size is going down, instead of getting smaller the divs will lay on top of each other

could you help me making them responsive?

### html

```
<div class="exampleboxcontainermainpage">
    <div class="exampleboxmainpage">
        <h1>create social media Buttons with html and css</h1>
        <br>

        <div class="socialmediacontainer">
            <a href="#" class="fab fa-facebook-square"></a>
            <a href="#" class="fab fa-youtube"></a>
            <a href="#" class="fab fa-google"></a>
            <a href="#" class="fab fa-twitter"></a>
            <a href="#" class="fab fa-instagram"></a>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br>
    </div>

    <div class="exampleboxmainpage2">
        <div class="exampleinsideboxmainpage">
            <pre class="prettyprint default">
                    <!-- Start of showing code -->
                    <xmp>

                    <div class="socialmediacontainer">
                  <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook-square"></a>
                  <a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
                  <a href="#" class="fa fa-google"></a>
                  <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
                  <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>   
                </div>

                    </xmp>

                    <!-- !!!!! End of showing Code !!!!!-->
                </pre>
        </div>

        <button onclick="window.location.href = 'tryyourselfcodes/howto_howto_social_button.php'; " style="left:30px;" class="buttontest">
            Try yourself >>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

### css

```
.exampleboxcontainermainpage{
padding-left:100px;
}
.exampleboxmainpage {
  background-color: #f3f4fa;
  border-style: unset;
  /* padding: 23px; */
  text-align: center;
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom:24px;
}
.exampleboxmainpage2 {
  background-color: #f3f4fa;
  border-style: unset;
  padding: 31px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 900px;
  height: 400px;
  position:relative;

  display: inline-block;
}
.exampleboxmainpage h3 {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;

}
.examplebox button {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;

}
.exampleinsideboxmainpage {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 700px;
  display: inline-block;


  border-style: unset;
}
.exampleinsideboxmainpage p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  display: inline-block;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

Try to use `flex` as its responsive and easy to use

> And on break-screen(below 767px mobile) i just change its direction to
>   `column` from `row`

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

[class*="box--"] {
    display: flex;
    margin: .25rem;
    height: 2rem;
    padding: .25rem;
    color: white;
}


.box--half {    
    background: blue;
    flex: 1 1 30%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
  .container{
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box--half">1</div>
    <div class="box--half">2</div>
</div>
```

[Read more about flex here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

Comment: hey thanks, I have 2 diffrenet divs inside the container, your example use 2 same divs

Comment: @SarahMilner You can use different `div`

Comment: I mean the css inside each div and the content is diffrenet

Comment: @SarahMilner Yes you can just replace that text with your desire div, or tell me ill update that for you

Comment: I did extacly like u said and it didn't work... that the page  freecodewiki.com I am testing in virtual server on my pc , but the page on the domain look the same

Comment: Ok can you tell me your screen size in px using chrom inspector

Comment: 1920x1080 screen

Comment: Can you please create a working example in snippet of stack-overflow just like mine, because i tested its working fine in above example

Comment: I think I fixed hold on

Comment: ok its working but now the divs are not centered, like 40 px padding from left side

Comment: @SarahMilner  Glad that you helped yourself, Good to hear that! cheers and up-vote please :)

Answer (score 0):

If you resist to use inline display instead advanced one like `flex` or `grid` you can use `media queries` to show your `div` under each other in smaller screen, for example I use `800px` for breakpoint. You can use `display: block`:

```css
.container>div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
  .container>div {
    display: block
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Content 1</div>
  <div>Content 2</div>
</div>
```